# How would I convert an entry in my list into a string?

Tags: python

This is my current code:

```
kwlist = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    text = url.get_text()
    if keywords in text:
        links = (url['href'])
        kwlist.append(links)
        '|'.join(kwlist)
colorlist = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    text = url.get_text()
    if color in text:
        colorlinks = (url['href'])
        colorlist.append(colorlinks)
        '|'.join(color)
#finallink = any(x in kwlist for x in colorlist)
#print(finallink)
kwset = set(kwlist)
colorset = set(colorlist)
intersection = str(kwset.intersection(colorset))
print(intersection)
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/' + intersection)
```

This is the print output:

```
{'/shop/tops-sweaters/deshwjqp5/i640qb2pu'}
```

But, this is the website that selenium is navigating to:

```
https://www.supremenewyork.com/%7B'/shop/tops-sweaters/deshwjqp5/i640qb2pu'%7D
```

I need selenium to navigate to:

```
https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/deshwjqp5/i640qb2pu
```

That is the same item in my list, just with out %7b' and '%7D
How would I change the list into my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

`%7B` and `%7D` are encoded `{` and `}` characters from the set after you call `str` on it.

You need to "unwrap" the value out of the set first. If you only want a single entry from `intersection`, and you know that it will always contain at least one element, you can convert it to a list, then take an element from it. Something like:

```
# Convert to list, then take the first element
intersection = str(list(kwset.intersection(colorset))[0])
print(intersection)
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/' + intersection)
```

If you can't guarantee `kwset.intersection(colorset)` will always return at least an element, you'll need to do some error handling, or switch to a different way to "unwrap" the set, like calling a defaulting `next` on an iterator of the set.